# Show symbol in legend

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I have a Highstock chart that has a legend.  Currently the legend is only showing a colored line for each series.  How can get this [**chart**](http://jsfiddle.net/FtPQa/) to show the symbol in the legend for each series?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3xPaM/), I think that it will meet your needs.